# Build custom query with gorm Golang lib

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#query

I want to build selectQuery base on some custom conditions

```
selectQuery := db.Select("username").Where("status = 'active'")
selectQuery.Limit(10)
if err := selectQuery.Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
//
} else {
//
}
```

Why limit is not applied?

It’s working if implemented with below code:

```
if err := db.Select("username").Where("status = 'active").Limit(10).Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
//
} else {
//
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why limit is not applied?

Because you're ignoring the return value of [Limit](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Limit). In effect, you're creating a query with a limit, then throwing it away without ever executing it.

You need to use:

```
selectQuery = selectQuery.Limit(10)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong and downvoted by mistake. I cannot de-unvote this unless it's edited, so as an excuse I upvoted another your answer.

Comment: Checked again on Limit function:
`// Limit specify the number of records to be retrieved
func (s *DB) Limit(limit interface{}) *DB {
    return s.clone().search.Limit(limit).db
}`
so this is a correct answer